# How to set different states based on checked/unchecked inputs with pre-loaded data

Tags: reactjs, use-state

I have two sets of data coming in from API, accountContacts & callReportContacts like so:

```
const accountContacts = [
  {
    Id: "3SLS-003QZ",
    "First Name": "Lynne",
    "Last Name": "Froisland"
  },
  {
    Id: "3SLS-003QA",
    "First Name": "John",
    "Last Name": "Doe"
  },
  {
    Id: "3SLS-003QB",
    "First Name": "Jane",
    "Last Name": "Doe"
  },
  {
    Id: "3SLS-003RL",
    "First Name": "Curtis",
    "Last Name": "Shrestha"
  },
  {
    Id: "3SLS-003S1",
    "First Name": "Susan",
    "Last Name": "Simoncelli"
  }
];

const callReportContacts = [
  {
    Id: "3SLS-003RL",
    "First Name": "Curtis",
    "Last Name": "Shrestha",
    checked: true
  },
  {
    Id: "3SLS-003S1",
    "First Name": "Susan",
    "Last Name": "Simoncelli",
    checked: true
  }
];
```

Now, callReportContacts **do not** have the checked attribute by default. Hence, I add it to the response before I set its state. I then merge both of them so that the items from callReportContacts replace the ones in accountContacts like so:

```
useEffect(() => {
  setMergedContacts(
    accountContacts.map((contact) => {
      const item = callReportContacts.find(({ Id }) => Id === contact.Id);
      return item ? item : contact;
    })
  );
}, []);
```

I then render the mergedContacts using an input checkbox component with a pre-checked state if its set to true, like so:

```
{mergedContacts.map(({ Id, 'First Name': firstName, 'Last Name': lastName, checked }) => {
    return (
      <ToggleOption
        contacts={contacts}
        setContacts={setContacts}
        deselectedContacts={deselectedContacts}
        setDeselectedContacts={setDeselectedContacts}
        key={Id}
        contactID={Id}
        label={firstName + ' ' + lastName}
        ischecked={checked}
      />
    )
  })
}
```

What I want is two set of states, contacts & deselectedContacts which will be POSTed to their respective API endpoints separately. If I check/uncheck an unchecked input, it should be added/removed from the contacts state and the same for a pre-checked input for the deselectedContacts state. Here's the [bare bones working link](https://codesandbox.io/s/morning-violet-m2ncv)

In the example, if I check/uncheck Lynne, John or Jane they should be added/removed from the contacts state and if I do the same for Curtis or Susan, they should be added/removed from the deselectedContacts state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take advantage of `checked: true` on the data that is coming from the API. This data, you are already storing on the `mergedContacts` - so you can use it as a flag if this object is initially checked. This will be used later on, on assessing whether or not to push to `contacts` or `deselectedContacts`.

[image]

With that said, I took a look at your `ToggleOption` component, and it looks like you are already passing that object attribute as a prop named `ischecked`, and furthermore, you are not mutating it - which makes the job easier.

What I did is I passed additional props to the `ToggleOption` component, the `deselectedContacts` state and the `setDeselectedContacts` state setter. After that, on the onChange/onClick events of the `ToggleOption` inputs, I passed along the `ischecked` prop which would indicate if the contact was initially checked.

```
return (
  <div className="toggle-option">
    <div onClick={() => handleToggle(ischecked)}>
      <input
        ref={toggleRef}
        data-id={contactID}
        onChange={() => handleToggle(ischecked)}
        ...
```

Lastly, on the `handleToggle` handler, I put conditions on what state needs updating depending on whether the contact was initially checked, again - I utilized the `ischecked` property.

```
const handleToggle = (ischecked) => {
  setCheckedState((prevState) => !checkedState);

  const item = {
    Id: toggleRef.current.getAttribute("data-id")
  };

  if (ischecked) {
    if (deselectedContacts.map((e) => e["Id"]).includes(item["Id"])) {
      setDeselectedContacts(
        deselectedContacts.filter((e) => e["Id"] !== item["Id"])
      );
    } else {
      setDeselectedContacts([...deselectedContacts, item]);
    }
  } else {
    if (contacts.map((e) => e["Id"]).includes(item["Id"])) {
      setContacts(contacts.filter((e) => e["Id"] !== item["Id"]));
    } else {
      setContacts([...contacts, item]);
    }
  }
};
```

CodeSandBox: https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-brown-6rczt?file=/src/App.js